# How do I view Instagram API permissions application status?

Tags: mobile, social-networking, instagram-api

I recently submitted an application to apply for Instagram's "basic" API access. they did note during the application process that they would **not** notify me if we were accepted or not. That's fine...but I've went back to the permissions overview page pretty regularly over the last week and can't find any information anywhere regarding the status of my application.

The majority of questions on here are dealing with what to do if you are denied...I'm simply trying to figure out how we know when we are accepted or denied. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The Permissions page is where you will find the status of your Instagram API permission. Attached image shows my permission statuses on that page.[image: Instagram API Permission Page]

Note that it took Instagram over 48 hours to review and approve my application.